# How do I make a VB 6.0 CheckBox control transparent?

Tags: user-interface, vb6, checkbox

We could not make the VB6.0 checkbox as a transparent one. Can you suggest me how to make check box as a transparent?

I searched internet and many sources indicates that checkbox cannot be made as transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I looked at this so I might be wrong but try using a `WLCheck` control and set it's `BackStyle` to transparent.

You can find information about how to install the WL controls here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184687

Comment: Be aware that those controls are not supported on Windows Vista or Windows 7. `MSWLess.ocx` is listed as unsupported here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do this easily in VB6, however, this [UserControl](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=62322&lngWId=1) may help you.